# C - Curl in kenel module

Tags: curl, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to trigger keyboard LED flashing, that I already can based on this example: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x1194.html

But somehow I need to reach an API and use the response of it. Is it possible to use curl inside a Linux kernel module? Or how should I do it otherwise?

Comment: You can create an API inside your kernel model that you call to enable the led, based on the external curl response.

Comment: You mean call a module function from a userspace code? I tried to look for it but with not much luck. Could you provide some resources on the subject please?

Comment: check this out https://web.archive.org/web/20160127023537/http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html , I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

There's a working kernel module here

[Isolate Kernel Module to a Specific Core Using Cpuset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288877/isolate-kernel-module-to-a-specific-core-using-cpuset/36379938#36379938)

This creates a device `/dev/toy`

To do what you want edit the following function to blink your LED.

```
static int toy_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep) {
  ....
  printk(KERN_INFO "open: called\n");
  return 0;
}
```

To trigger that function use this

```
cat /dev/toy
```