# Run a kernel thread on an isolated cpu core

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel

I boot my kernel

```
with isolcpus=3-7
```

and I want to run a thread on one of those isolated CPU cores.

Based on this [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36395424/1260543), I do:

```
ctx->workq = create_singlethread_workqueue("my_work");
struct workqueue_attrs *attr = alloc_workqueue_attrs(GFP_KERNEL);
alloc_cpumask_var(&attr->cpumask, GFP_KERNEL);
cpumask_clear(attr->cpumask);
cpumask_set_cpu(5, attr->cpumask);
apply_workqueue_attrs(ctx->workq, attr);
INIT_WORK(&ctx->work, my_work);
```

But it's not working. The following code reports 0:

```
static void my_work(struct work_struct *w) {
    printk("CPU is: %d\n", get_cpu());
    put_cpu();
```

How can I run this workqueue thread on a specific core (if possible an isolated one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already one API **`schedule_work_on`** in the mainline kernel which you can use to run your workqueue thread on a specific core.

Few years ago I have used same API for the same purpose.
Have a look in the sample code.

```
static void
 myworkmod_work_handler(struct work_struct *w)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "CPU is: %d\n", get_cpu());
    pr_info("work %u jiffies\n", (unsigned)onesec);
    put_cpu();
 }


 static int myworkmod_init(void)
 {
    onesec = msecs_to_jiffies(1000);
    pr_info("module loaded: %u jiffies\n", (unsigned)onesec);

    if (!wq)
            wq = create_singlethread_workqueue("myworkmod");
    if (wq)
            queue_delayed_work_on(2,wq, &myworkmod_work, onesec); //2 CPU no

    return 0;
  }
```

In your case I think you are using the **schedule_work** API which always hold the default CPU number. That is why you are getting the **CPU 0**. So you have to try the below one:

```
schedule_work_on(cpu_nr, &ctx->work);  //cpu_nr will the CPU no to be used.
```