# How to change scheduler policy in Loadable Kernel Module (LKM) in Linux?

Tags: linux, system-calls, scheduling, kernel-module, ioctl

I have written an LKM in Linux. The `ioctl` function, `my_ioctl` is called by a user-level program `foo.c`. I want to change the scheduling policy of `foo.c`. Therefore I am doing the following in my `my_ioctl` function from [this link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-deadline.txt):

```
struct sched_attr attr;
int ret;
unsigned int flags = 0;

attr.size = sizeof(attr);
attr.sched_flags = 0;
attr.sched_nice = 0;
attr.sched_priority = 0;

/* This creates a 10ms/30ms reservation */
attr.sched_policy = SCHED_DEADLINE;
attr.sched_runtime = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
attr.sched_period = attr.sched_deadline = 30 * 1000 * 1000;

ret = sched_setattr(current->pid, &attr, flags);
if (ret < 0) {
    perror("sched_setattr");
    exit(-1);
}
```

The sched_setattr is following:

```
int sched_setattr(pid_t pid,
          const struct sched_attr *attr,
          unsigned int flags) {
    return syscall(__NR_sched_setattr, pid, attr, flags);
}
```

I have changed the `syscall` to `sys_mycall` [because it's LKM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26952858/915843). `struct sched_attr` is also defined in the above mentioned Linux Kernel documentation link. However, I could not change the scheduling policy by this. It throws me error like `scheduling policy cannot be changed from kernel space`.
I don't understand why this is the case. There is an utility [`chrt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chrt.1.html) which does the same thing for a process from the user-space; then why is this not possible from a LKM? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show what your #include statements look like at the top of your file?

Comment: Im trying to reproduce your error, but my LKM doesn't recognize sched_setattr

Comment: It won't recognize. You have to write your own (kernel) library where you have to make kernel specific syscall i.e `sys_mycall` as I mentioned.
My `#include` has my own header file which has `sched_setattr` defined as I have shown in the main post.

Comment: Im curious, if you just want to change the scheduling parameters of a user level program, why do you need to go into kernel space at all? You can construct the desired sched_attr struct in userspace and then call the system call sched_setattr. If you pass in 0 for the PID, it changes the parameters on the calling thread.

Comment: That's true. It can be done from user space. However, we may need to have a central control because this is related to scheduling which may affect other processes. That's why kernel-space management is better, in my opinion.